# Asp.net Ajax Toolkit slider issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using asp.net ajax toolkit slider in data list. Following is code snippet:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                   
 <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="Slider" runat="server" Steps="1" 
 Minimum="1"  Maximum="4"  TargetControlID="txt"
 EnableHandleAnimation="true" />
```

the only problem is: it never slide to step 2. it slide to step 1, 3 and 4 only.